# How with vue-head plugin to set meta read from db?

Tags: vuejs2

Making vue/cli 4 app I want to add page head on data from database
I use https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head
But the problem is that title and meta are set with initial data of vars which I have 
in data block, but not from the values of the var I read from db. I do :

```
...
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueHead from 'vue-head'
Vue.use(VueHead)
Vue.use(VueRouter)


export default {
    ...
    data() {
        return {
            ...
            site_name : 'QQWWEERRTTYY',
            ...

        }
    }, // data () {


    head: {

        title: function () {
            console.log('-1 this.site_name::')
            console.log(this.site_name) // In console I see “QQWWEERRTTYY” value, but not value what I read from db
            return {
                inner: 'AAA : '+this.site_name
            }
        },

        meta: function () {
            console.log('-2 this.site_name::')
            console.log(this.site_name) // In console I see “QQWWEERRTTYY” value, but not value what I read from db
            return [
                { name: 'description', content: 'BBB Events of '+ this.site_name }
            ]
        },
    },

    ...

    mounted() {

        retrieveAppDictionaries('eventsTimelinePage', ['site_name'])
        bus.$on('appDictionariesRetrieved', (data) => {
            if (data.request_key === 'eventsTimelinePage') {
                this.site_name = data.site_name // I READ DATA FROM DB
            }
        })
    }, // mounted() {
```

I know that WATCH can be used in similar case, when I need to catch event when value was assigned
to the site_name var, but I do not know to can I use Watch is this case?

```
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3",
"vue-head": "^2.2.0",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head/issues/13), you can now `self.$emit('updateHead')` to force vue-head to recalculate based on reactive data.